# Nagios custom plugin issue - https authetication

Tags: nagios

I am writing a plugin to check authentication to a https site and then search for a text in the response html,body to confirm successful login.  I have created the following plugin

```
#!/bin/bash
add_uri='--no-check-certificate https://'
end_uri='/'
result=$(wget -O- $add_uri$1$end_uri --post-data=$2)
flag=`echo $result|awk '{print match($0,"QC Domain")}'`;
echo $flag
echo "Nagios refreshes properly1"

if [[ $flag -gt 0 ]] ; then
echo 'ALL SEEMS FINE!!'
exit 0
   else
echo 'Some Problem'
exit 2
fi;
```

When I execute this plugin directly from command line

```
./check_nhttps <url here>  '<very long post data with credential information>'
```

The plugin works as expected(For both + & - test cases) and there seems to be no issues.
But when the plugin runs from Nagios,

```
check_command                   check_nhttps! <url here>  '<very long post data with    credential information>'
```

It always shows critical error(Prints else condition text "Some Problem" too). 
P.S : Tried sending the post data with double quotes also.doesnt work!!

Please help!!!

Comment: When it comes to writing any script, the first thing you should always do is verify that your environment is set correctly.  You are calling wget,awk via the PATH, but are you sure your PATH variable is set correctly?  Consider either defining a PATH in your script or giving the fully qualified paths for any external commands.

Comment: why are you writing a plugin to do something that the stock check_http already does? don't reinvent the wheel. https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_http.html

Comment: @Zoredache- Thx. As I said, But still it runs properly properly, when i execute it independently i.e ./check_https. So, could this stil b a env issue?

Comment: @Keith - I tried that n tht was my first attempt,but openssl-devel package was not installed and I couldn't install it either as it searches for mirrirsto download n fails at doing so..So when I couldn't do tht, i tried this way, n it worked well as a stand alone script,iit just doesn't work from Nagios alone 

Comment: Add `set >/tmp/foo` and `echo "$result" >>/tmp/foo` to debug this further. Also add `-S 2>>/tmp/foo` to the `wget` command.

Comment: You couldn't figure out how to compile check_http wtih SSL, so you're trying to write your own plugin? Really? You should just install the plugins from your distro package manager, probably...

Comment: Finally it worked!!!  Turned out the arguments were in wrong ordering in commands.cfg for this new plugin!!!